# How can I create a new environment with mdframed and empty for exercise answers?

Tags: mdframed

I borrowed the following MWE from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94464/note-environment-with-mdframed) but I would like to be able to create an empty environment to use for exercise answer with variable vspace. The exam class has the \makeemptybox{} option, but I wish to use the tufte-handout class and the mdframed package because it allows page breaks.

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}

\global\mdfdefinestyle{exampledefault}{%
linecolor=lightgray,linewidth=1pt,%
leftmargin=1cm,rightmargin=1cm,
}

\newenvironment{mymdframed}[1]{%
\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={\tikz\node[fill=white,rectangle,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]    {#1};},
frametitleaboveskip=-0.5\ht\strutbox,
frametitlealignment=\raggedright
}%
\begin{mdframed}[style=exampledefault]
}{\end{mdframed}}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\section{Some text}

\blindtext\footnote{text ends here.}

\bigskip

\begin{fullwidth}
    \begin{mymdframed}{This empty frame} % requires a vertical space of 25cm
    \end{mymdframed}
\end{fullwidth}

\section{Another text\protect\footnote{to be continued after the empty frame with about 25cm}}

\blindtext

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want to add text in the space reserved for solutions, then a command seems the best choice. The `\solutionbox` command reserves by default 25cm (change to suit).

The macro `\fillwithspace` works by dividing the requested space by `\baselineskip`, rounding the result to an integer *n* and producing *n* one line (but otherwise empty) paragraphs.

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\fillwithspace}{m}
 {
  \prg_replicate:nn { \fp_to_int:n { #1/\dim_to_fp:n { \baselineskip } } }
   {
    \mbox{}\par
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\mdfdefinestyle{exampledefault}{%
  linecolor=lightgray,linewidth=1pt,%
  leftmargin=1cm,rightmargin=1cm,
}

\newcommand{\solutionbox}[2][25cm]{%
  \begin{fullwidth}
  \mdfsetup{%
    frametitle={\tikz\node[fill=white,rectangle,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]{#2};},
    frametitleaboveskip=-0.5\ht\strutbox,
    frametitlealignment=\raggedright
  }%
  \begin{mdframed}[style=exampledefault]
  \fillwithspace{#1}
  \end{mdframed}
  \end{fullwidth}%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\section{Some text}

\blindtext\footnote{text ends here.}

\bigskip

\solutionbox[25cm]{This empty frame}

\section{Another text}

\blindtext

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]